# get the Full name of the authenticated user

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

**Goal**

I have a WCF Service using Windows Authentication. I want to determine the Full name of the user that *connected*. The user can either be a domain or a local user. For local users, you can view the Full name in [Computer Management (local) > Local Users and Groups > Users > [user] > Full Name].

**Almost successful with FindByIdentity**

I can use UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity() to retrieve a UserPrincipal object, and then get it from UserPrincipal.DisplayName. The first parameter of FindByIdentity requires specifying ContextType, such as Domain or Machine.

- Calling FindByIdentity with ContextType.Domain and a local user, produces a "Specified Domain Does Not Exist or Could Not Be Contacted" exception
- Calling FindByIdentity with ContextType.Machine and a domain user, produces a UserPrincipal without a filled DisplayName property

So i would like to avoid guessing.

**Question**

- How can i get the Full name of the *connected* user?
- Or how can i distinguish whether the *connected* user is a domain user or a local user?

**Code so far**

```
string GetFullName()
{
    using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        string userName = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
        UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName);
        return u.DisplayName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Environment.UserDomainName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.userdomainname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Environment_UserDomainName) property to get the domain name of the current user. If the domain is not joined, the host name of the current user will be returned.

Comment: i'm not looking for information about the current user. that's why i emphasized "connected" user. i mean the user that connected and authenticated to the web service

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following for now. If anyone has any better ideas, then please post your answer

```
bool LocalUserConnected()
{
    string userName = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;
    return userName.StartsWith(Environment.MachineName + @"\");
}
```